# How to find this value: $\sum_{i_1=1}^n \sum_{i_2=1}^n \cdots\sum_{i_k=1}^n \cos\frac{k(i^k_1+i^k_2+\cdots+i^k_k)}{n}$

Tags: trigonometry

**Question:**

Find this value

> $$\sum_{i_{1} = 1}^{n}\sum_{i_{2} = 1}^{n}\cdots\sum_{i_{k} = 1}^{n} \cos\left(k\left[\vphantom{\Large A}\, i_{1}^{k} + i_{2}^{k} + \cdots +i_{k}^{k}\,\right] \over n\right)
> $$

This is an interesting problem,

My try: Let
$$x=\sum_{i_1=1}^{n}\sum_{i_2=1}^{n}\cdots\sum_{i_k=1}^{n}\cos\frac{k(i^k_1+i^k_2+\cdots+i^k_k)}{n}$$
$$y=\sum_{i_1=1}^n \sum_{i_2=1}^n \cdots\sum_{i_k=1}^n \sin \frac{k(i^k_1+i^k_2 + \cdots+i^k_k)}{n}$$
so
$$x+y=\cdots=f(n)?$$
$$xy=\cdots=g(n)?$$
But at last I failed.

This problem is from a magazine's open problem (2010).
Thank you for your help.

Comment: In other words $$x=\sum_{i_1=1}^{n}\sum_{i_2=1}^{n}\cdots\sum_{i_k=1}^{n}\cos{\frac kn\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^k i^k_j}$$

Comment: The only simplification I can think of is
$$x + iy = \sum_{m_1=1}^n \cdots \sum_{m_k=1}^n e^{i \frac{k}{n} (m_1^k + \cdots m_k^k)}
= \sum_{m_1=1}^n e^{i \frac{k}{n} m_1^k} \times \cdots \times
\sum_{m_k=1}^n e^{i \frac{k}{n} m_k^k}
= \left(\sum_{m=1}^n e^{i \frac{k}{n} m^k}\right)^k
$$
No idea how to make this any further.

Comment: Is it $\cos\frac{k(i^k_1+i^k_2+\cdots+i^k_k)}{n}$ or $\cos\frac{k(i^k_1+i^k_2+\cdots+i^k_k)\color{red}{\pi}}{n}$?